# Polymer 3, apollo-client, graphql and CommonJS modules

Tags: polymer, graphql, apollo-client, polymer-3.x, lit-html

Dears,

I'm trying to make GraphQL work with Polymer 3 (or lit-html)

Trying to use apollo-client (which seems has adapters for polymer-elements and lit-html) and stuck with problem of importing CommonJS modules (i.e. module.export) in Polymer:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '../../graphql/language/visitor.js' does not provide an export named 'visit'
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but if apollo-client provides [apollo-client/polymer](https://github.com/apollo-elements/apollo-elements/tree/master/packages/polymer) and [apollo-client/lit-apollo](https://github.com/apollo-elements/apollo-elements/tree/master/packages/lit-apollo) this should work somehow. I tried to do it by included guides but got no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use a build-time transform (e.g. a bundler like webpack) if you want to load a commonjs module via ES module import syntax.

Commonjs modules (`require(...)`, `exports.foo = ...`) are very different from ES modules, and usually require some pre-processing before they're loadable in the browser.